# add combobox to mainwindow

Tags: python, pyqt5, qcombobox, qmainwindow

I created a Main window with 2 button by pyqt5 and now i want to add a combo box to it. But if i keep App(QMainWindow), the combo box wont show. Only if i write App(QWidgets) it will show. Are there any way to add a combo box to main window ? here is my code:

```
class App(QMainWindow):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.title = 'Phan mem quan ly tai lieu- Tuan tien mom'
        self.left = 200
        self.top = 200
        self.width = 320
        self.height = 200
        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):
        self.setWindowTitle(self.title)
        self.setGeometry(self.left, self.top, self.width, self.height)

        button = QPushButton('chaychuongtrinh', self)
        button.setToolTip('bam vao nut nay de chay chuong trinh')
        button.move(100, 70)
        button.clicked.connect(self.on_click)

        button1 = QPushButton('kiemtra', self)
        button1.setToolTip('kiem tra thong tin')
        button1.move(200, 70)
        button1.clicked.connect(self.on_click)

        layout = QHBoxLayout()
        self.cb = QComboBox()
        self.cb.addItem("C")
        self.cb.addItem("C++")
        self.cb.addItems(["Java", "C#", "Python"])
        self.cb.currentIndexChanged.connect(self.selectionchange)
        layout.addWidget(self.cb)
        self.setLayout(layout)
        self.setWindowTitle("combo box demo")
        self.show()
    def selectionchange(self,i):
        print ("Items in the list are :")
        print(self.cb.currentText())
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`QMainWindow` is a special widget, it already has a layout, so we should not add another layout as shown in the image:

[image]

In this case you must create a new widget and place it in the central widget, in this new widget we must place the widget like the QPushButton or the QComboBox.

In your case the `QPushButton` are visible because if a widget passed a parent, it will be located in the position (0, 0) of the parent, and then you have moved it to a specific position with `move()`. In contrast, the combobox has no parent so it is not visible.

Also if you are going to use a layout, you should not use the move () function since the layout will expand throughout the widget. In the following example without using the layout:

```
def initUI(self):
    self.setWindowTitle(self.title)
    self.setGeometry(self.left, self.top, self.width, self.height)
    self.widget = QWidget(self)
    self.setCentralWidget(self.widget)
    button = QPushButton('chaychuongtrinh', self.widget)
    button.move(100, 70)
    button.setToolTip('bam vao nut nay de chay chuong trinh')
    button.clicked.connect(self.on_click)
    button1 = QPushButton('kiemtra', self.widget)
    button1.setToolTip('kiem tra thong tin')
    button1.clicked.connect(self.on_click)
    button1.move(200, 70)
    self.cb = QComboBox(self.widget)
    self.cb.addItem("C")
    self.cb.addItem("C++")
    self.cb.addItems(["Java", "C#", "Python"])
    self.cb.currentIndexChanged.connect(self.selectionchange)
    self.cb.move(300, 70)
    self.setWindowTitle("combo box demo")
```

[image]

with layouts:

```
def initUI(self):
    self.setWindowTitle(self.title)
    self.setGeometry(self.left, self.top, self.width, self.height)
    self.widget = QWidget(self)
    self.setCentralWidget(self.widget)
    layout = QHBoxLayout(self.widget)
    layout.addItem(QSpacerItem(139, 20, QSizePolicy.Expanding, QSizePolicy.Minimum))
    vlay = QVBoxLayout()
    vlay.addItem(QSpacerItem(20, 40, QSizePolicy.Minimum, QSizePolicy.Expanding))
    layout.addLayout(vlay)
    layout.addItem(QSpacerItem(139, 20, QSizePolicy.Expanding, QSizePolicy.Minimum))
    button = QPushButton('chaychuongtrinh', self)
    button.setToolTip('bam vao nut nay de chay chuong trinh')
    button.clicked.connect(self.on_click)
    button1 = QPushButton('kiemtra', self)
    button1.setToolTip('kiem tra thong tin')
    button1.clicked.connect(self.on_click)
    self.cb = QComboBox(self)
    self.cb.addItem("C")
    self.cb.addItem("C++")
    self.cb.addItems(["Java", "C#", "Python"])
    self.cb.currentIndexChanged.connect(self.selectionchange)
    vlay.addWidget(button)
    vlay.addWidget(button1)
    vlay.addWidget(self.cb)
    vlay.addItem(QSpacerItem(20, 40, QSizePolicy.Minimum, QSizePolicy.Expanding))
    self.setWindowTitle("combo box demo")
    self.show()
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Every widget needs `parent`.

For `QPushButton` you used `self` as parent. For `QComboBox` use `self` as parent too

```
self.cb = QComboBox(self)
```